# DB Settings in Eclipse Plugin Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jtds

I've been tasked with migrating a scheduling application across servers. I could see that this project was developed in Eclipse as an Eclipse Plug-in App. I looked at the source code, the corresponding xml files, ini files and every source that I could find but cannot locate where the DB Settings are stored.

So I am reaching out here in the vain hope that someone can point me to where I can possibly look. I tried to import the app into Eclipse but still no luck. All I want to do is to find out where the DB settings are stored (xml file, preferences etc) and update the settings accordingly.

We are using the jTDS-SQL Server driver.

I understand this is very vague, but will greatly appreciate any input in this regard.

Thanks in advance,
bee